# difference b/w right and left align for axis labels in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have created chart sample using highchart

here is my sample,

http://jsfiddle.net/ave71qvm/

```
 yAxis: {
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 100,
            y: 0
        },
 }
```

in this code when set align property as left axis label text-overflow as start and positioned as 100px but in same code i just changed align as right instead of left the label text-overflow as end also the value axis label title also moved.. why this happen? and what is exact scenario for this... can u please explain or whether it is a bug?

Comment: It looks like a bug. I have reported it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5464